# What can i do to become a manager without a degree

Tags: interviewing, management

I have been with the same organization for over thirty years. Would like to apply for a manager position over a role that I had been in for over 15 years. This role happens to be a buyer.  The manager position would be over ten buyers.  The problem is I was last in learning the new system we are currently using and only know the analyst part of it.  I do not have a degree either.  What can I do to prepare?
thank you.

Comment: How much of being the manager of the team requires you to be an expert in the system the team members use?

Comment: You think the major thing to think about to become manager is a (computer?) system you are using? You should find out what a manager really has to do in this position. The best way is to ask someone because nobody knows how the bosses decide in your company.

Comment: Why do you want to become a manager?

Comment: @Erik why do we care? OP is not asking "do i want to be a manager"

Comment: @bharal if you know the why, then you can give them better advice on where to start improving/working towards the goal.

Comment: Is having a degree a company rule or do managers tend to have a degree?

Answer (score 10):

You have two options.

1) You talk to your boss and ask: "What do I need to do to become a manager here?"  And then you work with your boss to achieve those goals.  Depending on your work, how often a new manager is needed, and politics (among other variables), you may be able to achieve this goal at your company.

2) You apply for managerial jobs in other companies.  If someone hires you, then you are now a manager.  Some companies will require some kind of degree and will not hire you, but others will overlook that.

That's how to become a manager.  How to BE a manager is a completely different question.  Many people become managers and turn out to be bad ones.  If your goal is to be a manager, try to add to that goal to being a good manager.

Comment: +1 - We don't even know if it really is a lack of a degree that's getting in the way.